# Photoshop artboards navigation without zoom out?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard

When I navigate to another artboard, the document zooms out to fit the window.  I have to zoom in to 100% again, then scroll to the top every time.

**Is there a way not to zoom out when doing so?**

What I do to navigate between artboards is hold on Opt/Alt, then Click on the artboard in the layers panel

Comment: Not enough information here. In what way are you navigating to another artboard so that the document zooms out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you're getting that result, but the simple solution is to pan from one artboard to another. **Hold down the spacebar and move your mouse to move around the screen.**

Comment: That's cool, is there a way to align/snap the artboard to center of the window while panning?

Comment: Nope. When using multiple artboards in Photoshop, the canvas is the guide for what is considered the center, not the artboards. Hopefully something Adobe is addressing.

Answer (score 1):

I added a shortcut to Collapse All Groups (this works on Artboards too)

[image: Collapse Groups]

This way I can quickly get to this state and Alt+Click an Artboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Option + click** on the Artboard layer

Comment: Hi Rob, welcome to GDSE, thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate a bit more on _how_ and _why_ that would work? Maybe also give the Windows alternative? Thanks for your time and effort and keep contributing!

Answer (score 0):

Another option (besides holding down space to pan to the other artboards) is using a touchpad when working with a MacBook or an iMac connected to a trackpad. Usually, the default settings allow for panning using three fingers on the trackpad at once. For me this lets me smoothly move from artboard to artboard without any zooming.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Window > Navigator